# How to insert the missing months (with value NA) in a time series data file using AWK

Tags: awk

am new to awk and I have a data file goes from Jan 1958 to Dec 2014, but some data are missing, for example here is a portion of the file where couple months are missing:

```
2009    6       0.273
2009    7       0.000
2009    10      4.07
2009    11      8.25
```

and I must add the missing lines with (NA) so the output should be like this:

```
2009    6       0.273
2009    7       0.000
2009    8       NA
2009    9       NA
2009    10      4.07
2009    11      8.25
```

I wrote this code and it seems to work but there is something missing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";y=1958;m=1}{t=mktime(y" "m" 01 0 0 0");y=strftime("%Y",t);m=strftime("%m",t)*1;\
    if(y==$1 && m==$2){
        print $0;
    }else{
        print y,m,"NA";
    }
    m++
}' filename
```

here is the result:

```
2009    6       0.273
2009    7       0.000
2009    8       NA
2009    9       NA
2009    10      NA
2009    11      NA
```

I think the solution is to stay in the same line after printing the NA, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you starting from 1958 in your script? It doesn't seem to correspond with your input/output.

Comment: this is just a portion from the file, where there are missing lines

Comment: Ok that's fine but you should make your question self-consistent. I would recommend that you changed it so that your code, input and output all match up.

Comment: sorry am not familiar with the rules, this is my 1st question, I edited now, is it more consistent now? thanks for the recommendation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd map the year/month combinations to a contiguous sequence of integers instead of using `mktime`; that makes it much easier to iterate over them. It could look like this:

```
awk -F '\t' '
  # provide functions to map year/month combinations to a contiguous
  # sequence of integers, and to reverse the transformation.
  function combine(y, m) { return y * 12 + (m - 1); }
  function month(c)      { return c % 12 + 1; }
  function year(c)       { return (c - month(c) + 1) / 12; }

  # In the beginning: Ensure input is split the same way as the output, and
  # prime the pump as though there had been a last line describing Dec. 1957
  # (so that Jan. 1958 comes next)
  BEGIN {
    OFS = FS
    last = combine(1957, 12)
  }

  # processing data:
  {
    # map to sequence
    this = combine($1, $2);

    # insert missing lines
    for(i = last + 1; i < this; ++i) {
      print year(i), month(i), "NA"
    }

    # start from here next time
    last = this
  }

  # then print input lines unchanged
  1' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to just populate an array with the values from your input file, then loop through all of your years/months and print the array value if populated and NA otherwise:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{val[$1,$2] = $3}
END {for (y=1958;y<=2014;y++) for (m=1;m<=12;m++) print y,m,((y,m) in val ? val[y,m] : "NA")}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | grep 2009
2009 1 NA
2009 2 NA
2009 3 NA
2009 4 NA
2009 5 NA
2009 6 0.273
2009 7 0.000
2009 8 NA
2009 9 NA
2009 10 4.07
2009 11 8.25
2009 12 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will help too

```
NOTE:IT will take the year and month from the first line of the file 

awk -F"    " '

NR==1{lastyear=$1;lastmonth=$2}
lastyear<($1-1) {  while (lastyear<$1)
                   {print "falta año"lastyear+1; lastyear++}
                } 
lastmonth<($2-1){ while( lastmonth<($2-1) || 
                         ( lastmonth<12 && lastmonth!=($2-1)))
                   {print $1 FS lastmonth+1 FS  "NA";lastmonth++1}
                 }

lastmonth=($2-1) && lastyear=($1-1){ print $0}

{lastyear=$1; lastmonth=$2}
END{
while(lastyear<2011){if(lastmonth==12){lastyear=lastyear+1; lastmonth=0}
while( lastmonth<12 ){print lastyear FS lastmonth+1 FS  "NA";lastmonth++1}
}
}

' file.dat


2009    6       0.273
2009    7       0.000
2009    8    NA
2009    9    NA
2009    10      4.07
2009    11      8.25
2009    12    NA
2010    1    NA
2010    2    NA
2010    3    NA
2010    4    NA
2010    5    NA
2010    6    NA
2010    7    NA
2010    8    NA
2010    9    NA
2010    10    NA
2010    11    NA
2010    12    NA
2011    1    NA
2011    2    NA
2011    3    NA
2011    4    NA
2011    5    NA
2011    6    NA
2011    7    NA
2011    8    NA
2011    9    NA
2011    10    NA
2011    11    NA
2011    12    NA
```